# Why don't changes in my alsamixer equalizer have any effect?

Tags: alsa

I have moved all of the sliders all the way up and all the way down, and nothing changes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are using the wrong output device (often happens on my notebook after removing the hdmi-cable).
Enter `pavucontrol` (commonly pre-installed) in the terminal and you will find selectionbars to change the device.